# How to undo approval or rejection in Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

Is it possible to undo an `accept` or `reject` vote on proposed changes in the documentation?
Seems like there is no way to handle miss-clicks.

Comment: "miss-clicks" or changed mind? Latter sounds far more probable. There is plenty of separation between the button controls

Comment: Well, it this case, a change of mind after a really short period of time. More of a miss-read than a miss-click.